# Know a short story (Heinlein?) about a man constantly fighting alien life forms, realizing at the end that they're projections of his own feelings?

Tags: story-identification, robert-a-heinlein, planets

I just saw an old interview of Roger Waters where he describes a sci-fi short story, probably by **Robert Heinlein**, that he read in his youth, so dating back to the 1960s at least, and I'd really like to find it & read it myself.

I'll transcribe his description directly:

> "It's about a guy on a colonized outer planet somewhere, and he spends
> all day going round the perimeter, and he has to be very quick on
> the draw cause there are stingers and zappers and crawlers and
> creepers flying at him from everywhere, you know, and he's like :
> pshhhyoo ! [mimes someone shooting] (...) At the end of the story, he
> makes the discovery that what he is experiencing is only a projection
> of who he is. And as soon as he discovers that, and manages to control
> his own agressive instincts, it stops happening, because it's all him,
> it's nothing to do with the outside world at all."

By the way, this is a middle-aged man's memory, so it's possible some elements are incorrect.

Comment: Sounds like a garbled version of *Deathworld* which was by Harrison, not Heinlein.

Comment: thanks for responding so quickly. It does sound similar, yep. But if it's the one it's very garbled indeed...

Comment: something by Robert Sheckley ???  Heinlein seems unlikely; I don't remember anything like that and am reasonably well versed ...

Comment: If it was a film I'd have said "Forbidden Planet" ( monsters from the Id!)

Comment: It's definitely not Heinlein.

Answer (score 10):

### [Deathworld](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deathworld) 1

Although it’s by Harrison not Heinlein. The details are not a precise match:

- the main protagonist is an outsider not a colonist
- it’s not “all him”, it’s all the colonists
- the realisation that the flora and fauna are reacting to the colonist’s hostility doesn’t stop anything but it shows a path to the future.

However, the overall thrust is so close that it *has* to be Deathworld 1:

- the colonists all have quick draw holsters
- there are definitely “stingers and zappers and crawlers and creepers flying”
- the “projection” is due to the fact that the flora and fauna is psychic and it and the colonists are caught in a vicious cycle of hate and violence
- the protagonist puts it together and tries, with varying success, to advise the colonists

Comment: Thank you for this. That's pretty much the conclusion I've come to : a very mangled memory of Deathworld, with only the central concept remaining.